How can I calculate the heat transfers caused in Venus's atmosphere by a stellaser?
In Isaac Arthur's video Winter on Venus, he discusses using a stellaser to heat Venus’s atmosphere and remove its gases, but he doesn't go into much detail about the heat transfer involved in it.
The sources document from Kurzgesagt about terraforming Venus covers the basic concepts of warming involved. They mentioned that particles move faster at higher temperatures. At a sufficiently high temperatures, they can escape- this is the mechanism known as Jean's escape. The temperature can be measured with the formula below:
$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{2 \cdot k \cdot T}{m}}$$
$$ T = \frac{v^2 \cdot m}{2 \cdot k}$$
Where v is the escape velocity in [m/s], k is the Boltzmann constant, T is the temperature in [K] and m is the mol mass in [kg/mol]
$$ \frac{(10360 m/s)^2 \cdot 0.044 \ kg/mol}{2 \cdot 8.314}= 284000K$$
This temperature is quite high and would likely be enough to melt the surface. When the stellaser is aimed at the atmosphere, the atmosphere absorbs the light, which is then converted into heat. If the atmosphere doesn't absorb all the light, then it will reach the surface, requiring even more energy to heat the atmosphere to the desired temperature (ignoring the fact that much of that heat will also be radiated away). Therefore the heating of the surface will probably depend on how much of the light reaches the ground and how much heat is conducted from the atmosphere to the surface. How can I calculate how hot the surface will even get?
How can I calculate how hot the surface would get in this situation?
Once the atmosphere is removed, one would probably want to cool the surface quite a lot. Since Venus will need either hydrogen or water imported to terraform it, does adding ocean’s worth of water ice from other celestial bodies significantly speed up the cooling process?

PS: I originally asked about multiple aspects of the stellaser in a previous question, but since it was too many in one, I now have moved them into separate ones.
